# Unable to retrive the current guest id using public API url of softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

unable to retrieve the id of the current node using public softlayer url.

> curl -X GET -u xxxx:xxxxxx
>   https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getId.json
>   12345

where as the same request returns errors with public endpoint.

> curl -X GET -u xxxx:xxxxxx
>   https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getId.json
>
> {"error":"Access Denied. ","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Could anyone tell the reason for this behavior, is this expected?

Comment: are you running the request into the virtual server or bare metal server taht you desisre to identify?

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza yes I am executing the curl on the machine for which I need ID. I tried this on both virtual server and barematel and I see the same response(works with private api url but not with public).

Comment: Ok this is an issue I am gonna report him,but I do not know when this is gonna be fix it, if you want it you can report it by yourself by opening a ticket in softlayer

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza Thank you. I've opened a softlayer ticket as well, they suggested me to open it here as well, as the response will be quicker here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. The [SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata) is only accessible over the private endpoint. This is also the reason that you can call it without a Username or API key

```
root@wp:~# curl -X GET https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getId.json
35200757
```